# How to make query with grouping by foreign keys with ordering by sum of field

Tags: django, django-queryset

For example I have a model:

```
class Reward(models.Model):
   user = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile)
   amount = models.IntegerField()
```

I want to get such statistics:

```
[{ 
   "user": user1,
   "total_amount": 100500, // Sum of amount field of all rewards for this user
   "total_rewards": 13 // Count of rewards for this user
},
{
   "user": user2,
   ...
}
]
```

This list should be ordered by `total_amount` field. How should I do such query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that with [`annotate`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/aggregation/)

```
from django.db.models import Count, Sum
UserProfile.objects.annotate(
    total_amount=Sum('reward__amount'),
    total_rewards=Count('reward')
).values('id', 'total_amount', 'total_rewards').order_by('total_amount')
```